# Rails: can't correctly invoke nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following routes:

```
shallow do
  resources :countries do
    resources :airports
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble with invoking two of the routes.

The `airports_controller.rb` file begins

```
def create
  Rails::logger.debug "!!! Building airport with parameters #{params}"
  @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
  Rails::logger.debug "!!! Found airport #{@country.name}"
  @airport = @country.airports.build(params[:airport])
```

The last line gives the error `Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`, but the params I'm calling with are

```
!!! Building airport with parameters {"airport"=>{"iata_code"=>"CCC",
"icao_code"=>"CCCC", "name"=>"Airport 3", "city"=>"City 3", "latitude"=>"1.5",
"longitude"=>"1.5"}, "country_id"=>"980190962", "controller"=>"airports",
"action"=>"create"}
```

and as far as I can see all of those are in my permitted parameters:

```
def airport_params
  params.require(:airport).permit(:iata_code, :icao_code, :name, :city, :latitude, :longitude, :notes, :country_id)
end
```

Secondly, my `airports\_form.html.erb` begins `<%= form_for [@country, @airport] do |f| %>`, but that gives an error `Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'airports_path' for #<#<Class:0x4b0ba30>:0x55a2e48>`. Yes, that path is undefined, but I was trying to get to path `country_airports_path`, which *is* defined.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried running `rake routes`? Because `airport_path` is supposed to be defined.

Comment: Yes, I have run rake routes. Yes, airport_path is defined, but the code isn't routing to that (and I don't see why it should. I'm not after a single airport, I'm after all the airports in a country: country_airports_path, which is also defined but not being invoked).

Comment: To clarify why I don't want airport_path, when I create an airport I don't want to route to a view of that airport, I want to route back to the list of all airports in that country.

Answer (score 0):

In "def create"

```
def create
  ...
  @airport = @country.airports.build(airport_params)
```

You've correctly created the "airport_params" function, however you're not calling it. That should explain the `ForbiddenAttributesError`.

As for the undefined method, at first glance it looks like an incorrect association, are your models correctly related (i.e. `belongs_to` and `has_many`)? If so, you could try adding `url: country_airports_path` to the `form_for` field.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause of the FrbiddenAttributeError [slaps head].

airport.rb begins

    class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :country

and country.rb begins:

    class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :airports

So my associations look right to me. I'll try adding the URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Attributes**

The attributes error you've received is basically caused by your non-use of [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

Rails 4 introduced `strong_params` to give you the ability to define specific attributes to pass to your model (prevents mass assignment). The problem you have is that you're using the `Rails 3` way - passing all of the attributes without whitelisting them

As pointed out, you'll be better doing this:

```
#app/controllers/airports_controller.rb
Class AirportsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @airport = Airport.new(airport_params)
   end

   private

   def airport_params
      params.permit(:airport).permit(:your, :params).merge(country_id: params[:country_id])
   end
end
```

However, I believe there's something deeper you need to consider.

You're currently using `.build` for your airport model object. Whilst there's nothing *wrong* with this, you need to consider *what* you're trying to achieve...

The `Airport` model object is a standalone object. You can easily associate it with your `Country` model by setting the [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your strong params (demonstrated above)

If you use this line: `@airport = @country.airports.build`, you're working with the `Country` object, which IMO will open yourself up to errors down the line. As mentioned, there's nothing "wrong" with what you're doing; it's just that I'd either work with the Airport model directly (as written above), or use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to work with the `Country` model

--

**Route**

Secondly, your path error is going to be caused by your [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

`form_for` builds a form from an ActiveRecord object - which it does by taking arguments such as `model_name` to build the "url" / "action" for the form.

This means every time you populate a `form_for` object with an ActiveRecord object (variable), Rails will build a route based off of what you pass it (it does not know whether the object is nested or not)

```
<%= form_for @airport do |f| %>
  # builds route using "airport_path"
<% end %>
```

If you want to create a *nested* form, you'll be much better using an array of ActiveRecord objects, as to provide Rails with the knowledge you're using a *nested* resource:

```
<%= form_for [@country, @airport] do |f| %>
   # builds route using "country_airport_path"
<% end %>
```

Comment: On the first part, I'm not sure what errors I'm opening myself up to by manipulating the country model. Conceptually, airports are *not* standalone, they can only exist within a country (which is why they're nested); creating them within a country (and elsewhere making sure that a country with airports can't be deleted) ensures that logical integrity is maintained. Could you clarify what the problem is?

For the nested form, I'm doing *exactly* what you say I should be doing, and it's routing to country_airport_path - but there is no country_airport path, only country_airports_path.

Comment: Further, I think I should be using the <%= form_for @airport do |f| %> format, but that's not building a route to airport_path, it's building a route to the non-existent airports_path.